# In Angular2, how do I display an object consisting of a Tuple that's sent from a .NET Core controller?

Tags: angular, rest, controller, tuples, angular2-observables

I have the following controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok(new {
            val1 = "value 1",
            val2and3 = ("value 2", "value 3")
        });
    }
}
```

I also have the following interface and function in Angular:

```
export interface TestInterface {
  val1: string;
  val2and3: [string, string];
}

getTest(): Observable<TestInterface> {
  const data$ = this.httpClient
    .get<TestInterface>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Test');

  return data$.pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
  );
}
```

A problem seems to occur in the *getTest()* function above when I try to obtain data from the controller. In its *tap* function, I'm able to log the non-Tuple string's value but not those of the Tuple. *console.log* outputs what follows: `{"val1":"value 1","val2and3":{}}`

I call *getTest()* from another place in Angular, with the following lines of code:

```
let values: TestInterface | undefined;

this.apiService.getTest().subscribe({
  next: data => values = data
});

console.log('Values:' + values?.val2and3);
```

Logging *values?.val2and3* results in the following output: `Values:undefined`.

I'm too new to Angular to discover what's going wrong. How do I achieve my objective (which is to define the *values* variable with all the data sent by the controller)?

Comment: If you work with Google Chrome, you are able to see with DevTools (F12) under the network tap, how the data comes from the controller. Could you post that informations, also? That makes it easier for us to find the correct interface, for you.

Comment: I'm new to DevTools, but in its Network tab, the response code is 200 (ok) and the "Response" sub-tab shows `{"val1":"value 1","val2and3":{}}`, whereas the "Preview" sub-tab shows `{val1: "value 1", val2and3: {}}` on line 1, `val1: "value 1"`on line 2, and `val2and3: {}` on line 3.

Comment: Ah, ok. If the backend transmit you nothing to the frontend, it is impossible to get data in it. It seems, that the .net json converter has troubles with tuples. The solution of this link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854979/c-sharp-mvc-cant-deserialize-a-tuple) .. was, to create a custom class for it.
Please change your tuple to a small model.